# Scala Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, response

How to get Response Body from End point ? I am Sending request to Endpoint, I want to know, how to get the response string.

```
    val complexRequest = ws.url(serviceEndpoint).withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/xml")
    val result = complexRequest.post(leadXml).map { response =>
      logger.info(s"response $response")
      if (response.status == 200) {
        val res = response
        logger.info(s"status passed.. $res")
      }
      else {
        val res = response
        logger.info(s"status failed.. $res")

      }
    }
```

Comment: Is this test code or is it inside a controller?

Comment: It is inside services,now i got the response. And i have return the response to controller via promise.

Answer (score 1):

`response.body` you can also use PlayJson to validate it and change it to a workable object!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Helper class

```
import play.api.test.Helpers._
val result: Future[SimpleResult] = …
val bodyAsBytes: Array[Byte] = contentAsBytes(result)
```

Or JavaResultExtractor

```
    akka.util.ByteString body = play.core.j.JavaResultExtractor.getBody(result, 10000l, mat);
```

Or `JavaBodyPartser`

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaBodyParsers